# FullCalendar rerenderEvents and refetchEvents on Arrays

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using the Full Calendar with JSON data.  Because the json data returned to me is not the format the full calendar accepts, I cannot use the JSON url as the source directly.  Moreover, I need to manipulate the data to show different things between the Day and Month view.

So I set up the calendar to initially have an event source with an empty array.  On the ViewDisplay call back (this is triggered on the init of the calendar or when view changes between Month and Day) I call a function to retrieve the JSON data, manipulate it, and fill up the event Array.  At the end of that function, I call refetchEvents.  That doesn't seem to work.  The display does not show any event data still.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like this is exactly what you need:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/

in your events function, you'd write your own ajax call and call the callback when you have the data